# Is this transitivity proof correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given this sets A={1,2,3,4} and B={1,2,3,4} and relation C = {(1,1),(3,4),(2,2),(3,3)} we know it is transitive because, even if a pair starting with 4 doesn't exist, it doesn't disqualify the expression as transitive. Also, we have (3,3) as (a,b) and (3,4) as (b,c) so (a,c) must be (3,4) which is already in it. This is transitive.

This is what I got from its definition, but I don't know if a pair doesn't exist automatically becomes true.

Comment: Strangely worded but essentially fine.